# Mock beans with Mockk failed in Spring Projects

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

This is a none Spring Boot project.

I try to use `mockk()` to mock a bean in the controller tests, but failed.

The `PostController` depends on bean `PostRepository`, here try to use a `mockk()` bean to mock the `PostRepository` in our test config.

```kotlin
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = [PostControllerTest.TestConfig::class])
class PostControllerTest {
    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostControllerTest::class.java)
    }

    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = [PostController::class])
    internal class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        fun postRepository(): PostRepository = mockk<PostRepository>()
    }

    @Autowired
    lateinit var posts: PostRepository

    lateinit var client: WebTestClient

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        log.debug("calling setup...")
        client = WebTestClient.bindToController(PostController::class)
            .configureClient()
            .build()
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun teardown() {
        clearAllMocks()
    }

    @Test
    fun `get post by id`() = runTest {
        val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        coEvery { posts.findById(any()) } returns
                Post(
                    id = id,
                    title = "test title",
                    content = "content of test title"
                )
        client.get().uri("/posts/$id")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk
            .expectBody().jsonPath("$.title").isEqualTo("test title")

        coVerify(exactly = 1) { posts.findById(any()) }
    }

}
```

The example project used the latest Spring 6.1.x WebFlux, Kotlin(1.9.22)/Kotlin Coroutines(1.7.3), and Java 21.

Check source codes here, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/kotlin-co

In before experience, I applied same mode which used Mockito to [mock beans in Java codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/r2dbc/src/test/java/com/example/demo/web/RouterFunctionTest.java), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This actually makes a lot of sense. `Mockk` alone isn't prepared to work with Spring. It is just a mocking library and so when you do this:

```
@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    log.debug("calling setup...")
    client = WebTestClient.bindToController(PostController::class)
        .configureClient()
        .build()
}
```

it will try to recognize the controller, but that won't happen because at this point the Spring `WebTestClient` has no idea where to pick up the `posts` repository.

For your example what you probably need to do is something slightly different like this:

```
@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    log.debug("calling setup...")
    client = WebTestClient.bindToController(PostController(posts))
        .configureClient()
        .build()
}
```

By handing in the instance of the controller with your mocked repository, then the `WebTestClient` will be able to recognize the complete controller and I'm pretty sure this will work for you. The reason being is that I have reproduced the exact same `404` problem you are having in one of my projects using a similar code like your example and after changing it, it worked perfectly.

However if you are working with `mockk` and want to mock spring beans, then it is probably better to use something different called [Spring MockK](https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk). It works much in same way as `Mockito` does, but it is more adapted to work in a `Kotlin` style.